# loadash sortBy should return on encountering null

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I have the following data `[1,2,3]` when I use sortby on the key it works and I get the output as `1` (since I am getting the smallest element).

Now I sometimes receive `[1, null, null]` data from backend in this case `sortBy` still sorts and gives me 1 as output. If I have one null value I want my function to return null.

Can I still use `sortBy` to get null or the least of all values or I should use something totally different?

TIA

Comment: Why dont you check at first place if array contains null. Why you need null from `sortBy` function?

Comment: You can't use `Array.includes` to check if null is present and return null if so?

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```js
const nums = [1, null, 3];
 
_.sortBy(nums, (n) => n === null ? -Infinity : n);
```

Result: `[null, 1, 3]`;

you can add your own sort function as the second argument in the [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) function